How to dynamically route request based on header?
In a kubernetes setup with istio service mesh, developers are allowed to deploy different versions on same app. Request should be routed to these different deployments based on header values.
In other words, requirements are similar to this Lyft blog
If deployments are static, it can be achieved with DestinationRule, VirtualService.
How to achieve the same in more dynamic scenario where deployments are added and removed often?


Maybe it's not the best solution, but you can define the routing rules in your DestinationRule and VirtualService resources and dynamically configure them after the new deployment was added, then run helm upgrade.

Sure, this is one way. I'm looking to automate the dynamic configuration of DestinationRule and VirtualService on changes in deployment. Looking for answers on how to do that.

You're effectively doing a Canary Deployment. You will label each deployment and associate that label with a Destination Rule. A Virtual Service will route traffic based on a header to the Destination Rule and therefore the  deployment.
Just label your deployments for the Destination Rule
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: helloworld-v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: helloworld
        version: v1

